# Insert into a table the year, week number and week start day between two dates, given the first day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two dates, being 2008 (consider 2008-01-01) and 2025 (consider 2025-12-31), I need to be able to add data in my table that has these columns.

```
| Year | WeekNumber | WeekStartdate |
```

For example given that the first day of the week is default/Sunday:

| Year | WeekNumber | WeekStartdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2008 | 1 | 2008-01-06 |
| 2008 | 2 | 2008-01-13 |
| 2008 | 3 | 2008-01-20 |

And so on, until the end date.

But in case the **first day of the week** *changes* to Monday or whatever, this would need to change the week start date.

Example, if FirstDayOfWeek = Tuesday then:

| Year | WeekNumber | WeekStartdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2008 | 1 | 2008-01-01 |
| 2008 | 2 | 2008-01-07 |
| 2008 | 3 | 2008-01-14 |

And so on until 2025.

I came up with some ideas for this, some go to CTEs but I really don't understand how they work within an insert into procedure thingy.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Update_Week_Numbers_Table
    @FirstDayOfWeek TINYINT 
AS 
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Beginning DATE = CONVERT(DATE, '2008-01-01')
    DECLARE @End DATE =  CONVERT(DATE, '2025-12-31')
    DECLARE @Current DATE = @Beginning

    DECLARE @CurrentWKno INT = 1

    DELETE Week_Numbers

    WHILE @Current < @End  
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Week_Numbers ([WYear], [Wkno], [WSDate]) 
        VALUES (DATEPART(YEAR, @Current), @CurrentWKno, @Current)

        SET @Current = DATEADD(week, 1, @Current)

        IF @CurrentWKno = 53
            SET @CurrentWKno = 1
        ELSE
            SET @CurrentWKno = @CurrentWKno + 1

        CONTINUE  
    END
```

But I suppose it's not even remotely close to what I might need...

Comment: Why do you need to create a table - you can use DATEPART(iso_week, {date}) to get the week number - which always starts on Monday and ends on Sunday.  In general, week numbers don't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple set based solution that should get what you need. I'm assuming you don't have a Numbers table, so it creates one via CTEs, then just does some DATE functions.

```
DECLARE
    @DateStart DATE = '2008-01-01'
    ,@DateEnd DATE = '2025-12-31'
    ,@FirstDayOfWeek TINYINT = 3
;

WITH N1 (Number) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1)
    ,N2 (Number) AS (SELECT N1.Number FROM N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2)
    ,N3 (Number) AS (SELECT N2.Number FROM N2 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N3)
    ,N4 (Number) AS (SELECT N3.Number FROM N3 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N4)
    ,N5 (Number) AS (SELECT N4.Number FROM N4 CROSS JOIN N4 AS N5)
    ,Numbers AS (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM N5)
SELECT
    WYear = YEAR(DTE.WSDate)
    ,Wkno = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(DTE.WSDate) ORDER BY DTE.WSDate)
    ,DTE.WSDate
FROM Numbers AS NMS
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES(DATEADD(day,Number-1,@dateStart))
    ) DTE (WSDate)
WHERE DTE.WSDate < @DateEnd
    AND DATEPART(weekday,DTE.WSDate) = @FirstDayOfWeek
;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I just had to create a stored procedure to be able to call this and its amazing. Thanks lots!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to be able to calculate the week number - using logic similar to how ISO generates the week number based on different start days of the week, then you can review this code:

```
Declare @start_day int = 0
      , @start_date datetime = '2000-12-25'
      , @end_date datetime = '2099-12-31';

/*
    @start_day = day of week to calculate
        0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, 4 = Thursday, 5 = Friday, 6 = Saturday

    
*/

   With t(n)
     As (
 Select t.n 
   From (
 Values (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)
      , (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)
      , (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)
      , (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) As t(n)
    )
      , dates (inputDate)
     As (
 Select Top (datediff(day, @start_date, @end_date) + 1) 
    dateadd(day, checksum(row_number() over(Order By @@spid) - 1), @start_date + @start_day - cast(@start_day As bit))
   From t t1, t t2, t t3, t t4
    )
      , weekNumbers
     As (
 Select d.inputDate
      , week_day       = datepart(weekday, d.inputDate)
      , us_week        = datepart(week, d.inputDate)
      , iso_week       = datepart(iso_week, d.inputDate)
      , week_number    = (datepart(dayofyear, (((cast(d.inputDate As int) + 53691 - @start_day) / 7 * 7)) - 53687) + 6) / 7
      , week_number_0  = (datepart(dayofyear, (((dt.intDate + iif(dt.intDate > -8, 8, 2) - @start_day) / 7 * 7)) - 4) + 6) / 7
      , week_number_d0 = (datepart(dayofyear, dateadd(day, (((d2.intDate + 8 - @start_day) / 7 * 7)) - 4, cast('0001-01-01' As date))) + 6) / 7
      , dt.intDate
      , d2_intDate     = d2.intDate
   From dates            d
  Cross Apply (Values (cast(d.inputDate As int)))                                               As dt(intDate)
  Cross Apply (Values (datediff(day, cast('0001-01-01' As date), cast(d.inputDate As date))))   As d2(intDate)
    )
 Select *
   From weekNumbers;
```

The formula for the column 'week_number' allows for datetimes from 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31.  If you are using date or datetime2 data types then 'week_number_d0' works for all dates from 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31.